# How to use django-filter on RawQuerySet?

Tags: python, django, django-filter

i have a problem.
The error is this

```
AttributeError at /tracker/
'RawQuerySet' object has no attribute 'all'
```

This is because i am using django-filter on a raw query set from sql query (i cannot use django filtering)

this is the code i am having problems with:

```
def track1(request):
    sql = """
        select 1 as id,
            p.name project,
            i.title issue,
            u.name,
            replace(ROUND(t.time_spent/3600.0, 1)::text, '.', ',') as spent,
            TO_CHAR(t.spent_at + interval '2h', 'dd.mm.yyyy HH24:MI:SS') date_spent, substring(n.note for 300) note
        from issues i
        left join projects p on p.id = i.project_id
        left join timelogs t on t.issue_id = i.id
        left join users u on u.id = t.user_id
        left join notes n on n.id = t.note_id
        where (t.spent_at + interval '2h') between '2022-06-01' and '2022-06-30 23:59:59'
        order by 5, 1, 2
    """

    user_spent_on_project = UsersSpentOnProjects.objects.raw(sql)
    filter = UsersSpentOnProjectsFilter(request.GET, queryset=user_spent_on_project)
    user_spent_on_project = filter.qs

    context = {
        'user_spent_on_project' : user_spent_on_project,
        'filter' : filter
    }

    return render(request, 'trackApp/track1.html', context=context)
```

Is there any way i could convert this raw query set to something that has Model.objects.all()

Comment: `all()` is an ORM function that returns all instances of that model, your raw SQL is creating a filter so the two are doing fundamentally different things. A similar action would be to remove the `where` clause in your raw SQL. However, it won't fix your error because you can't call `.all()` on the rawqueryset still. Why can't you just use the ORM?

Comment: As @0sVoid says, it is better to use the ORM if possible, if you have doubts about how to make a complex filter, you can leave the indications of what you want to filter.

Comment: Yes you are both right. My biggest problem is that i don't know much about databases and funny i didn't know that you can do this in your db "CREATE VIEW AS ....rest of the sql query" this practically fixed my problem because now i can create model through this "table" and it's ORM friendly of course since i'm not using raw query.. Thank you for having interest in this problem, i managed to fix it in the end :D